# In what sense $\alpha \times \alpha$ is the initial segment generated by $(0,\alpha)$ in $Ord \times Ord$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

This is from Jech's book on set theory:

> We define a well ordering of the class $Ord \times Ord$ of ordinal pairs.
>   Under this well ordering, each $\alpha \times \alpha$ is an initial segment of $Ord^2$. Moreover, the well ordered class $Ord^2$ is isomorphic to the class $Ord$ and we have a one-to-one function $\Gamma$ of $Ord^2$ onto $Ord$:
>   We define
>
> \begin{align}(\alpha,\beta) < (\gamma,\delta)  \iff&  
> \max\{ \alpha, \beta \} < \max\{\gamma,\delta\},\\ &\text{or }
> \max\{ \alpha, \beta \} < \max\{\gamma,\delta\}\text{ and }\alpha < \beta,\\& \text{or }\max\{ \alpha, \beta \} = \max\{\gamma,\delta\}\text{ and }\alpha = \beta\text{ and }\beta < \delta.\end{align}
>
> The relation $<$ defined above, is a linear ordering of the class $Ord \times Ord$. Morover, if $X \subset Ord \times Ord$ is nonempty, then $X$ has a least element. Also, **for each $\alpha$, $\alpha \times \alpha$ is the initial segment given by $(0,\alpha)$.**

I am trying to understand, how come $Ord \times Ord$ is isomorphic to $Ord$. How come the relation is one-to-one? For example:
**Applying the above relation, If $\alpha \times \alpha$ is the initial segment given by $(0,\alpha)$,what will the initial segment given by $(\alpha,\alpha)$ represent in $Ord^2$?**

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

It means that $\min(\mathsf{Ord\times Ord}\setminus(\alpha\times\alpha))=(0,\alpha)$.

Note that all the pairs in $\alpha\times\alpha$ have both coordinates less than $\alpha$, so indeed $(0,\alpha)$ is above all of them in this order, and any pair $(\beta,\gamma)$ which is less than $(0,\alpha)$ is necessarily a pair such that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are less than $\alpha$, and therefore $(\beta,\gamma)\in\alpha\times\alpha$.

Comment: But what does this say about $(1,\alpha)$. We have $(0,\alpha)<(1,\alpha)<(\alpha,\alpha)$. So, the initial segments, generated by $(0,\alpha)$ and $(\alpha,\alpha)$ cannot be the same, right...?

Comment: The pair is not the same as the Cartesian product.

Comment: Do you mean that we have $\alpha\times \alpha \subset Ord\times Ord$ and $(0,\alpha)\in Ord\times Ord$?

Comment: Yes. So one is an element of the order, and one is a subset.